# Repeat the n records set again and again till it reaches to last

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a table as shown below. It has 147 rows (column1). Column4 has 9 distinct values. Now I need to repeat the column4 result set till it reaches to last record 147. I have pasted below output query. Please advice.

```
Lookup  Col2      col3   col4 
--------------------------------
1       14967081  10     1351327
2       14967082  20     1351328
3       14967083  30     1351329
4       14969084  45     1351330
5       14969085  52     1351331
6       14969086  67     1351332
7       14969087  79     1351333
8       14969088  81     1351334
9       14969089  97     1351335
10      14969090  10     NULL
11      14969091  11     NULL
12      14969092  12     NULL
13      14969093  13     NULL
14      14969094  14     NULL
15      14969095  15     NULL
..      ...       ..     NULL
..      ...
147     14969118  190    NULL
```

Desired output should look like this:

```
Lookup  Col2      col3   col4 
---------------------------------
1       14967081  10     1351327
2       14967082  20     1351328
3       14967083  30     1351329
4       14969084  45     1351330
5       14969085  52     1351331
6       14969086  67     1351332
7       14969087  79     1351333
8       14969088  81     1351334
9       14969089  97     1351335
10      14969090  10     1351327
11      14969091  11     1351328
12      14969092  12     1351329
13      14969093  13     1351330
14      14969094  14     1351331
15      14969095  15     1351332
..      ...       ..     1351333
..      ...       ..     1351334
..      ...       ..     1351335
..      ...       ..     1351327
..      ...       ..     1351328
..      ...       ..     ......
147     14969118  190    1351327
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issues are you facing with that solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the lookup is really sequential with no gaps, you can use modulo arithmetic and a window function:

```
select t.*,
       max(col4) over (partition by lookup % 9) as imputed_col4
from t;
```

If you cannot rely on `lookup` to be gapless, then you can use `row_number()` as well:

```
select t.*,
       max(col4) over (partition by seqnum % 9) as imputed_col4
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by lookup) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by lookup;
```

Both of these can also be incorporated into `update` statements.  For instance:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(col4) over (partition by lookup % 9) as imputed_col4
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set col4 = imputed_col4
    where col4 is null;
```

Here is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Ohh `max() over rownumber` so simple, I had a complete brain-fail, I did a row-number join instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use reminder operator and map the values as given below:

```sql
declare @table table(Looku int,  Col2      int, col3   int, col4 int)

insert into @table 
values
(1       ,14967081  ,10     ,1351327)
,(2       ,14967082  ,20     ,1351328)
,(3       ,14967083  ,30     ,1351329)
,(4       ,14969084  ,45     ,1351330)
,(5       ,14969085  ,52     ,1351331)
,(6       ,14969086  ,67     ,1351332)
,(7       ,14969087  ,79     ,1351333)
,(8       ,14969088  ,81     ,1351334)
,(9       ,14969089  ,97     ,1351335)
,(10      ,14969090  ,10     ,NULL    )
,(11      ,14969091  ,11     ,NULL    )
,(12      ,14969092  ,12     ,NULL    )
,(13      ,14969093  ,13     ,NULL    )
,(14      ,14969094  ,14     ,NULL    )
,(15      ,14969095  ,15     ,NULL    )


SELECT t.looku, t.Col2, t.col3, ISNULL(t.col4, c.col4)  
FROM @table  as t
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
select t1.looku , t1.col4
FROM @table AS T1
WHERE T1.Looku <= 9 ) as c
ON iif(t.Looku % 9 = 0,9,t.Looku % 9) = c.looku
```

| looku | Col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14967081 | 10 | 1351327 |
| 2 | 14967082 | 20 | 1351328 |
| 3 | 14967083 | 30 | 1351329 |
| 4 | 14969084 | 45 | 1351330 |
| 5 | 14969085 | 52 | 1351331 |
| 6 | 14969086 | 67 | 1351332 |
| 7 | 14969087 | 79 | 1351333 |
| 8 | 14969088 | 81 | 1351334 |
| 9 | 14969089 | 97 | 1351335 |
| 10 | 14969090 | 10 | 1351327 |
| 11 | 14969091 | 11 | 1351328 |
| 12 | 14969092 | 12 | 1351329 |
| 13 | 14969093 | 13 | 1351330 |
| 14 | 14969094 | 14 | 1351331 |
| 15 | 14969095 | 15 | 1351332 |

Comment: Hum, didn't think of that. Much simpler than mine, but only works if `Lookup` is monotonically increasing with no gaps starting at 1

Comment: @Charlieface, yes. from the OP sample data, it looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to calculate a row-number on the distinct values that you have, calculate a row-number on the whole table then join the two with a modulo calculation.**

```sql
SELECT
    t.Lookup,
    t.Col2
    t.col3
    ISNULL(t.col4, DistinctValues.col4)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                          ORDER BY Lookup) - 1
    FROM table
) t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT col4,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(Lookup)) - 1,
        cnt = COUNT(*) OVER ()
    FROM table
    WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY col4
) DistinctValues
  ON DistinctValues.rn = t.rn % DistinctValues.cnt AND t.col4 IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

My idea is nested while. Updating col4 with value 1351327 and increment on each loop. When updating 9th times, reset value back on 1351327 and increment again while id wasn't reset.
I wrote query like this:

```
declare @val int =  1351327, @rows int = 0, @inc int = 0, @id int = 1

while @rows < 147
begin
    while @inc < 9
    begin
        update tbl
        set col4 = @val
        where lookup = @id
        
        set @rows= @rows + 1
        set @val = @val + 1
        set @inc= @inc + 1
        set @id = @id + 1
    end

set @inc = 0
set @val = 1351327
end
```

[Check here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94e18abdc14b446b277ca4739c0c4674) output on db fiddle.